# Creating webhook using Github API isn't working in Django using requests

Tags: python, github, python-requests, github-api, webhooks

I am using the following code to try and create a webhook for a repository that I own. However I keep getting the following response:

```js
{u'documentation_url': u'https://developer.github.com/v3', 
 u'message': u'Body should be a JSON Hash'}
```

The code:

```
hook = {u'name': u'web', u'active': True, u'config': {u'url': u'http://my/payload/destination'}}
t = json.JSONEncoder().encode(hook)
p = requests.post('https://api.github.com/repos/:user/:repo/hooks', params=t, headers={'content-type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'token ' + token})
```

And here is the output of t:

```js
{"active": true, "config": {"url": "http://my/payload/desination"}, "name": "web"}
```

And the authorization token in the header is formatted as such:

```
token REDACTED
```

I know this SHOULD work, so I went to `http://www.hurl.it/` using the exact same info as above, and it was successful. Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not providing a POST body; `params` is for *URL query parameters*. Use the `data` argument instead:

```
p = requests.post(
    'https://api.github.com/repos/:user/:repo/hooks', data=t, 
    headers={'content-type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'token ' + token})
```

`params` puts the parameters after the `?` in the URL instead.

As of `requests` version 2.4.2 you can also leave the JSON encoding to the `requests.post()` call; just pass in the payload to be encoded as the `json` keyword argument. The correct Content-Type header will be added for you:

```
hook = {u'name': u'web', u'active': True, u'config': {u'url': u'http://my/payload/destination'}}
p = requests.post(
    'https://api.github.com/repos/:user/:repo/hooks', 
    json=hook, headers={'Authorization': 'token ' + token})
```

Comment: That is what I get from copying some of my code from a requests.get() request. Thank you very much, that makes a lot of sense. I will accept your answer when I can in a few minutes!